# How to add text after the AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I go about this

I want to add something like a greeting, say "Hi James" before the Sliders , something like this

https://i.postimg.cc/cJQb8Cyz/Screenshot-1664302329.png

I wanted the greeting to be there , not sure how to go about it.

My source code is looking thus

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TransactionDetails {
  String? avatar;
  String? name;
  String? date;
  String? amount;

  TransactionDetails({
    this.avatar,
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.amount,
  });

  TransactionDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    name = json['name'];
    date = json['date'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['avatar'] = avatar;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['amount'] = amount;
    return data;
  }
}

Future<List<TransactionDetails>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => TransactionDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "My Bank",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Poppins",
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 27),
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$5200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$1200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Text(
                "Recent Transactions",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
                    future: fetchAlbum(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                                ),
                                title:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                                trailing: Text(
                                    snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
                              );
                            });
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                      }
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }))
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

How do i put the greeting before the Sliders? Help is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Text` widget for  text and `SizedBox` for space. You can also use `Padding` widget around `Text`.

```dart
),
body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ), //gap or use Padding widget
    Text("Greatins"),
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ), //gap
    SizedBox(
      height: 150,
```

with Padding widget

```dart
body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 8,
        bottom: 8,
      ),
      child: Text("Greatins"),
    ),
    SizedBox(
```

```dart
class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 1),
            child: Text(
              "My Bank",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Poppins",
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'),
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 27),
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 8,
                bottom: 8,
              ),
              child: Text("Greatins"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$5200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: 319,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const Text(
                      '\$1200.00',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Text(
                "Recent Transactions",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
                    future: fetchAlbum(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                      snapshot.data![index].avatar.toString()),
                                ),
                                title:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                                trailing: Text(
                                    snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                                subtitle:
                                    Text(snapshot.data![index].date.toString()),
                              );
                            });
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                      }
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }))
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, But i wanted something with Padding, Bold etc... Tried this and it worked, but to make it Larger and more cute.

Comment: You can use `Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: x, left: x), child:Text(` .. or EdgeInsets.symmetric .

Comment: dont want to get Lost with this, Can you please show me in the code you wrote. Would make more sense there pls